# How do I increase number in SKAction.moveToY by my score in Sprite Kit Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have my score func set:

```
func updateScore(scoreToAdd:Int) {
    score = score + scoreToAdd
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + String(score)
}
```

and I want to increase the speed of this falling object:

```
SKAction.moveByX(0, y: ??? , duration: 8.0)
let MoveYAction = SKAction.moveToY(-30, duration: 8.0)
```

Every time the score goes up one. So I want it to be that value (-30 + score x a speed)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to return an `SKAction` from your `updateScore` method:

```
func updateScore(scoreToAdd:Int) -> SKAction {

    score = score + scoreToAdd    
    scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + String(score)    
    return SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -30 - score), duration: 8.0)
}
```

Then when you call the updateScore method, you set it to a variable to use the action:

```
let moveAction = updateScore(scoreToAdd: xyz)

node.run(moveAction) //notation in swift 3
```

Note however, this won't make the object fall *faster* like you're wanting it to, it will just make it fall *farther*. If you want it to fall faster, you'll want to decrease the duration of the `SKAction` in the `updateScore` method.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response but I'm not sure I was able to get my goal from this code. See that code on the bottom in my first post, was in a different func called LaunchEnemy(). I'm sorry, I should've made that more clear. How could I make it so both funcs interact with each other?

Comment: I was able to derive my answer from this answer! The SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -30 - score), duration: 8.0) helped a lot! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad I could help!